# Exoplayer offline - download consumes more data than file size

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, mpeg-dash, exoplayer2.x

I am using Exoplayer version 2.9.6 to stream videos. Recently I added download video feature to my app using Exoplayer's in built download manager. The problem with download is that it consumes more data while downloading. For a 18 mb video (the size is determined by checking the size of exo player's download folder after download) , it takes about 240 mb of network data. I am using DASH to stream videos. Any one know why this is happening.?

Comment: The code is too large to show here. I am using the same implementation as that of demo app provided by exo player

Answer (score 0):

Storage is often reported in Megabytes and network usage in Mega bits.

That would mean your 18 MegaByte file would need 144 Megabits of network transmission. If you add the networking overhead then you may find this explains  much of the difference you are seeing.